# How units are dependent in systemd when used After option in unit file?

Tags: systemd

Suppose service A is dependent on service B with help of After= option in its unit file e.g 
A.service contains:
    [Unit]
    After=B.service

In this scenario, A will start only after B is started. 
But what if, due to some reasons, B is stopped or restarted? Would service A also stop/restart?

I know there is TopOf option is just for this. But I want to know what After= does.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't restart or stops.
A.service starts after B.service and if B.service goes down A.service is still working ;)